# div contenteditable with elements readOnly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How would be the approach to achieve non-corrupted text, like [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/chips) ? Bsically, I need when clicked, do not be able to change the text, but instead select the hole element. Preferible with angular, something like readOnly approach maybe?

To be more clear, i need something like:

```
 <div contenteditable="true">some text with a <div class="chip">chip</div></div>
```

chip class's content, should be read only and cannot be corrupted.

Comment: You need to be clearer.  Are you asking how to use angular-material?  Or asking how to make readonly md-chips?

Comment: how to make a read only chip, nop a md-chip, kind of the approach from scratch